# Need help inserting values from sql_fetch_array into a function

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, function

pardon me if this is a noob question.

I am trying to call a public function delete() from a .php file in a folder.

The public function delete() is in fileA.php

I created another file: fileB.php and use it to call the public function in fileA.php.

However, the code doesn't seems to work.

This is what i have in fileB.php:

```
function crondel() {

    $sql_del2 = new Item;

    $oc_t_item_description="oc_t_item_description";

    $sql_del="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP($expiry_date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))"; 
    $result_del = mysql_query($sql_del);


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_del)) {


             $itemid = $row['pk_i_id'];
             $secret = $row['s_secret'];
             //$sql_del2 = "DELETE FROM $oc_t_item_description WHERE 
                            //fk_i_item_id = '$criteria'";
             //$result_del2 = mysql_query($sql_del2);

           }

    $secret_new=$secret;
    $itemid_new=$itemid;

    $result_del2 = $sql_del2->delete( $secret_new, $itemid_new );


    }
```

The problem is the script is exceuted and no errors were reported. However, it didn't produce the expected results.

I think the problem lies with inserting the values obtained from mysql_fetch_array into the public function delete() called above.

Other than that, I can't think of anything else why it doesn't work. 
Appreciate any help. Thanks!!

/////EDIT //////

This is function: delete()

public function delete( $secret, $itemId )
        {
            $item = $this->manager->findByPrimaryKey($itemId);

```
        osc_run_hook('before_delete_item', $itemId);

        if( $item['s_secret'] == $secret ) {
            $this->deleteResourcesFromHD( $item['pk_i_id'] );
            Log::newInstance()->insertLog( 'item', 'delete', $itemId, $item['s_title'], $this->is_admin ? 'admin' : 'user', $this->is_admin ? osc_logged_admin_id() : osc_logged_user_id() );
            $result = $this->manager->deleteByPrimaryKey( $itemId );
            if($result!==false) {
                osc_run_hook('after_delete_item', $itemId, $item);
            }
            return $result;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You need to `include` or `require` fileA.php somewhere. But you are using Objects, shouldn't `->delete()` be defined in the `Item` class?

Comment: How have you debugged this? Have you tested this theory by `var_dump(..)`-ing the variables involved to see their contents?

Comment: I also assume you only want to delete the last item?

Comment: Hi! I did include fileA.php at the header of the code. just didn't show it here. it didn't occurred to me that the current code only contain the last row of my query which isn't what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the source of the delete() -function?
Anyhow, your $itemid and $secret will only contain the last row of your query, cause you reassign the value and don't do anything after that. I think you ment to do this to get all results:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_del)) {
    $result_del2 = $sql_del2->delete( $row['s_secret'], $row['pk_i_id'] );
}
```

Edit: delete() does not take array as a parameter, but s_secret and pk_i_id.

Comment: Hi! i have added the source of the delete() function in the initial post. Thanks for your help!